# Usage of begrudge

Tags: word-usage, word-order, indirect-objects, direct-objects

While looking up this word, I found a weird usage, for example:

> She begrudged Martin his affluence
>
> She begrudged her friend the award.

Applying common sense, it's clear that she envied her friend because of the award her friend received. But why is *begrudged* used in this manner, where the thing which is envied comes after the object? Any other insights will be appreciated. How do such types of sentences fit into longer sentences where multiple clauses are used?

Comment: Why do you think this is unusual? How is it different from other ditransitive verbs? "I begrudged Martin his affluence", "I gave Martin the book", "I passed Martin the salt", "I kicked Martin in the balls".

Comment: The first reference comes straight from [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/begrudge?region=uk&q=begrudge). How is that weird? What would you say is not wierd?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I may find things weird even though they maybe perfectly reasonable as i'm a non-native speaker of English. Anyhow, what i meant to ask was, why isn't the first sentence framed like this: "She begrudged Martin's affluence" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indirect objects precede direct ones in English:

- I gave ***him*** a real tongue-lashing.
- She begrudged ***me*** my success.
- They asked ***us*** our names.
- Give ***me*** a break!
- Buy ***her*** a new car.

The indirect object, or dative of interest, comes after the verb but before the direct object proper.

Comment: I think the problem might be that the OP's confused about which is the indirect and which the direct object for *begrudge*. After all, you *hold a grudge* against a *person,* but you *begrudge* a *thing*.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks. This also helped: http://www.slu.edu/colleges/AS/languages/classical/latin/tchmat/grammar/g-indob.html

Comment: @PeterShor I have been looking for similar ***be-*** verbs that take an indirect object. You can find some if you try hard enough, but almost all of them are quite old.  Nearly the only contemporary example I could find is that you can bequeath someone your estate.

Comment: What's interesting is that the 'grudge' part is beverbed, while the indirect object gets repeated. A close paraphrase is _She held/holds a grudge about my success_. A very strange construction.